# Use of adjectives in compound nouns

Tags: compound-words

Here are two compound nouns

1. Heavy pipe fitting works.
2. The biggest pipe fitting works.

In the first compound noun the adjective *heavy* qualifies the first noun *pipe*. But in the second compound noun, the adjective *biggest* qualifies the second noun *works*, while the place of both the adjectives in both the sentences is same.

1. I want to know what the rule is of using adjectives with compound nouns. How do I know which adjective qualifies which noun?
2. What is meant by *works*? In what sense has it been used. Is it plural or singular? I tried to search this word on the internet and in a dictionary but found nothing.

Comment: I think the first version could also be mis-understood as commenting the total weight of pipe fitting art installations in theory.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't believe there is a particular rule. The association is primarily based on meaning, and in cases where meaning is not obvious, ambiguities can arise. That is not to say that there is a preferred pattern, such as eg left-to-right.
   In your first example, *(((heavy pipe) fitting) works)*, it is fairly clear that only the pipes can be heavy. So interpreting the phrase structure is easy. The second one, *(biggest ((pipe fitting) works))* makes more sense than *(((biggest pipe) fitting) works)*, unless it is clear from context that the works is only fitting the biggest pipes. Also, the definite article favours the first interpretation.
2. *Works* here is used in the sense of "factory". An [online etymological dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/works) states it's "[m]eaning "industrial place" (usually with qualifying adjective) is from late 15c." While the form itself is plural, it would be used in the singular to apply to a particular factory (which might contain multiple workshops). For example *steel works*, *locomotive works*, or company names such as [Hawthorne Works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_Works) or [Baldwin Locomotive Works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldwin_Locomotive_Works).